# Rails migration: only for schema change or also for updating data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm a junior Rails developer and at work we faced the following problem:

Needed to update the value of a column only for one record. 
What we did is creating a migration like this:

```
class DisableAccessForUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    User.where(name: "User").first.update_column(:access, false)
  end
end
```

Are migrations only for schema changes?

What other solutions do you suggest?

PS: I can only change it with code. No access to console.

Comment: Perhaps make a special route like /239fh2938fh239f8h2 with that one change in it, deploy, then remove it and redeploy.

Comment: How about creating a rake task?

Comment: If you do not have access to the production console: Try to get a new job and in the mean time, write a script that breaks a lot of stuff and hand it to the OPs guys.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The short version is, since migrations are only for schema changes, you wouldn't want to use them to change actual data in the database.

The main issue is that your data-manipulating migration(s) might be ignored by other developers if they load the DB structuring using either `rake db:schema:load` or `rake db:reset`. Both of which merely load the latest version of the structure using the `schema.rb` file and do not touch the migrations.

As Nikita Singh also noted in the comments, I too would say the best method of changing row data is to implement a simple rake task that can be run as needed, independent of the migration structure. Or, for a first time installation, the `seed.rb` file is perfect to load initial system data.

Hope that rambling helps.

**Update**

Found some documentation in some "official" sources:

- [Rails Guide for Migrations - Using Models in your Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations). This section gives a description of a scenario in which data-manipulation in the migration files can cause problems for other developers.
- [Rails Guide for Migrations - Migrations and Seed Data](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data). Same document as above, doesn't really explain why it is bad to put seed or data manipulation in the migration, merely says to put all that in the `seed.rd` file.
- [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750829/877472). This person basically says the same thing I wrote above, except they provide a quote from the book **Agile Web Development with Rails (3rd edition)**, partially written by **David Heinemeier Hansson**, creator of Rails. I won't copy the quote, as you can read it in that post, but I believe it gives you a better idea of why seed or data manipulation in migrations might be considered a bad practice.

Comment: Isn't the point after all that you shouldn't commit the schema.rb file to the code repository, is it's a generated file anyway? (Btw, I do agree on the idea of not seeding in the migrations, but data migration looks like something else to me.)

Comment: @bertbruynooghe I used to think that as well for the same reason, but this file is a bit of a different case; you probably do want to commit `schema.rb` so that you can quickly rebuild the db structure using `db:schema:load` in any other environment (or a coworker) without worrying about the hassle of running every darn migration file. I think it also says in the file something like "...it is strongly recommended to check this in to your version control system...", so I would tend to believe that it is considered best practice to commit that file.

Comment: The referenced sources all recommend avoiding seed data and models in migrations - none of them discourage actually migrating your data.  If you need to change a prefix on all instances of some column in a table to match your new codebase, I haven't seen any good argument not to use a migration for that.  Setting up rake tasks to do that is just reinventing the wheel (or the migration process, as the case may be).

Comment: Admittedly I'm several years removed from this issue, and rails as well, but the general idea is about nicely separating schema changes from data changes to give you a bit more flexibility. You can easily 'dry run' the rake task without implementing specific rollback logic, and you have the choice of including it (or not) in your deployment. There are lots of other reasons (and lots in support of migrations too); this is one of those situations where you technically 'can' do something, but is it really a good idea, or appropriate for the given situation. I'd rather just keep it separate.

Comment: Anyone looking for the first section linked (since removed) can find it here in the Github history: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f387aa1/guides/source/migrations.md#using-models-in-your-migrations

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with using a migration to migrate the data in your database, in the right situation, if you do it right.

In order to clarify "the right situation", the main thing to think about is whether you're adding config or seed data, or just modifying the representation of data that is generated and maintained by the application.  Consider the following examples:

1. Adding a prefix to certain 'ids' stored as strings, to match a new id formatting requirement.

   - This is a migration. The ids were already there, just in the wrong format.  They are not seed or config data, they are part of the data that is generated by the application itself.
2. Populating a new 'categories' table that is required for the app to run.

   - Not technically a migration.  This is seed data, and should be added to `seeds.rb` (though you may *also* choose to include it in the migration that adds the table)

As for "doing it right", there are two related things you should avoid in your migrations (as many have mentioned), neither of which preclude migrating data:

1. It's not safe to use your models in your migrations.  The code in the `User` model might change, and nobody is going to update your migration when that happens, so if some co-worker takes a vacation for 3 months, comes back, and tries to run all the migrations that happened while she was gone, but somebody renamed the `User` model in the mean time, your migration will be broken, and prevent her from catching up.  This just means you have to use SQL, or (if you are determined to keep even your migrations implementation-agnostic) include an independent copy of an ActiveRecord model directly in your migration file (nested under the migration class).
2. It also doesn't make sense to use migrations for seed data, which is, specifically, data that is to be used to populate a new database when someone sets up the app for the first time so the app will run (or will have the data one would expect in a brand new instance of the app).  You can't use migrations for this because you don't run migrations when setting up your database for the first time, you run `db:schema:load`. Hence the special file for maintaining seed data: `seeds.rb`.  Data *migration* usually involves changing, not adding data.  This doesn't even mean you can't add data in a migration though. It just means that if you do need to *add* data in a migration (in order to get production and everyone's dev data up to speed), and if that data is necessary for the app to run (qualifying it as seed data), you need to add it to `seeds.rb` too!

Neither of these, however, mean that you shouldn't use **migrations** to **migrate** the data in existing databases.  That is what they are for.  You should use them!

Comment: I agree that DML changes are okay in migrations.  Even the rails guides say so: 
"Migrations can also be used to add or modify data. This is useful in an existing database that can't be destroyed and recreated, such as a production database."
(https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data)

Answer (score 2):

Migrations are fine for schema changes. But when you work on much collaborated projects like pulling code everyday from lot of developers.

Chances are you might miss some migrations(Value update migrations..No problem for schema changes) Because migrations depends on the timestamps.

So what we do is create a **rake task in a single namespace** to update some table values( Be careful it does not overwrites)

And invoke all the rake task in that NameSpace  whenever we update the code from Git.

Answer (score 2):

Making data changes using classes in migrations is dangerous because it's not terribly future proof.  Changes to the class can easily break the migration in the future.

For example, let's imagine you were to add a new column to user (sample_group) and access that column in a Rails lifecycle callback that executes on object load (e.g. after_initialize).  That would break this migration.  If you weren't skipping callbacks and validations on save (by using update_column) there'd be even more ways to break this migration going forward.

When I want to make data changes in migrations I typically fall back to SQL.  One can execute any SQL statement in a migration by using the execute() method.  The exact SQL to use depends on the database in use, but you should be able to come up with a db appropriate query.  For example in MySQL I believe the following should work:

```
 execute("UPDATE users SET access = 0 WHERE id IN (select id from users order by id limit 1);")
```

This is far more future proof.

Comment: Looks lie a fake argument to me. If you apply the techniques described in [this article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations) and test your migrations, they're as future proof as any other code.

Comment: Actually, no they aren't.  You didn't read my argument.  If you use an after_initialize referencing a column that is defined in a migration to the future of the one that is being run, it will still fail even with a reset columns call, because the column doesn't exist in the database at the time the migration is run.

Comment: I think I got what you mean: making data changes using _actual model_ classes in migrations is dangerous? I absolutely agree on that point: your migrations should have no reference to any code that can change later on. But if you create dummy classes inside your migration as the previous link described, I don't see what can go wrong. Furthermore, if you test your migrations and use CI, you will detect this problem as it occurs.

Comment: Your assuming that using dummy classes is sufficient.  In my experience fixing this issues at ~10 consulting clients and employers over the past few years I've never found that to be the case.  In my experience whenever a model class is being used in a real-life migration, it's because the author wants to take advantage of the actual behavior of that model - filtering using existing methods/scopes or making database changes contingent on existing (and often complex) state.  If you're using anything beyond basic AR behavior (where, etc.) then the dummy class approach doesn't solve anything.

Comment: As a side note, from the development team perspective, this is often characterized by the sudden and inexplicable failure of the migration process - suddenly 'rake db:create db:migrate' fails out in the middle of the process, usually on a migration that was written months earlier.  Everyone is confused, and a surprisingly large amount of time is spent trying to figure this out.  New developers and contractors are told to clone an existing db, instead of dealing with the problematic migration process.  Lots of sturm und drang, easily avoided.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old and I think rails approach changed over time here. Based on https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data it's OK to feed new columns with data here. To be more precise your **migration** code should contain also "down" block:

```
class DisableAccessForUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    User.where(name: "User").first.update_column(:access, false)
  end
  
  def down
    User.where(name: "User").first.update_column(:access, true)
  end  
end
```

If you use **seeds.rb** to pre-fill data, don't forget to include new column value there, too:

```
User.find_or_create_by(id: 0, name: 'User', access: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

A migrations is simply a structured way to make database changes, both schema and data.
In my opinion there are situations in which using migrations for data changes is legitimate.

For example:

1. If you are holding data which is mostly constant in your database but changes annually, it is fine to make a migration each year to update it. For example, if you list the teams in a soccer league a migration would be a good way to update the current teams in each year.
2. If you want to mass-alter an attribute of a large table. For example if you had a slug column in your user and the name "some user" would be translated to the slug "some_user" and now you want to change it to "some.user". This is something I'd do with a migration.

Having said that, I wouldn't use a migration to change a single user attribute. If this is something which happens occasionally you should make a dashboard which will allow you to edit this data in the future. Otherwise a rake task may be a good option.

Comment: An admin dashboard is a really neat thing.

Comment: I disagree with using migrations update data.  Consider this...  You update N records using a Rails migration, and there's no problem.  Later, when trying to re-deploy your app on new service, which requires you to run all of your migrations.  The not-a-schema change migration runs, blows up, and now you're trying to debug a problem you never needed to have.  I'm a strong advocate of putting data migrations in a Rake task.

Comment: Usually when deploying the app from scratch you use the schema.rb or structure.sql files which are generated by rails in order to setup the database (as in `rake db:setup`). Never saw someone deploying a big application by running all the migrations from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, changing particular records may work, but I'm not sure about that.

In any case, it isn't a good practice, migrations should be user for schema changes only.
For updating one record I would use console. Just type 'rails console' in terminal and input code to change attributes.

Comment: The message said "No access to console".