# Build db:rake task from existing Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, dbmigrate

I have a project that has had alot of editing to the postgresql database.

I am tring to find out is there a way to build a new db:rake file so i can rebuild the database on new server easily. Without manually editing the db:rake files.

thanks

```
Ruby 1.9.3
CentOS 6.4
Ruby on Rails 3
postgresql 9.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity, I am assuming you are referring to the migration files when you mention *db:rake files*.

In Rails, you don't want to rebuild the database using migration files. They can quickly become outdated, referring to things that no longer exist, etc. Instead, it is best practice to recreate the database using your `schema.rb` file instead. This is touched on [an answer I wrote a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19635244/877472). In short, the `schema.rb` file represents your database table structure; a snapshot, if you will. Note that **it does not contain data**, only the table structure.

In your scenario, in order to create, or ensure your `schema.rb` is up to date, you simply need to dump the schema, like so:

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

This regenerates the `schema.rb` file. Then, to rebuild the database from this file in another environment, simply reload the schema, like so:

```
rake db:schema:load
```

As stated above, the `schema.rb` does not contain any data from the tables, it merely represents the structure. If you want to preload the database with initial / default values, you will want to use the `seed.rb` file. Simply write your `.create` statements, and run it like so:

```
rake db:seed
```